# Tab support with mvvm light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have an old android application that I want to bring over to multiple platforms using MVVM Light.

For the most part, I am able to port the business logic to the PCL, create the view models and get that side of things working.

While I'm happy with using the INavigationService for navigation, I don't seem to be able to find any sort of documentation on if tab pages/uitabviewcontroller/pivot pages are supported using MVVM Light (I've spent a fair while trying google and bing as well as searching the MVVM Light docs and projects on github).

Is there support for tab layouts and if there is, is there a simple to follow set of instructions on getting this going?

Thanks